# Sub query Multiple row

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

If I add distinct to sub-query then would it bring distinct row or multiple row..??

I have a query and I getting error

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

and query is this

```
SELECT DISTINCT(o.order_id), (SELECT DISTINCT op.vendor_id FROM order_product op 
WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id) AS vendor_id, CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) 
AS customer, CONCAT(o.shipping_address_1, o.shipping_address_2, o.shipping_city,',',
o.shipping_zone,',',o.shipping_country,'-',o.shipping_postcode) AS address, 
(SELECT os.name FROM order_status os WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id
AND os.language_id = '1') AS status, (SELECT delivery_boy_name FROM delivery_boys db
WHERE o.delivery_boy_id = db.delivery_boy_id) as delivery_boy, o.delivery_boy_id, 
o.order_status_id, o.total, (SELECT SUM(op.total) FROM order_product op WHERE 
op.order_id = o.order_id AND op.vendor_id = '37') AS total, (SELECT os.cost FROM 
order_shipping os WHERE os.order_id = o.order_id AND os.vendor_id = '37') AS 
shipping_cost, o.currency_code, o.currency_value, o.date_added, o.date_modified 
FROM `order` o LEFT JOIN `order_product` op ON (o.order_id = op.order_id) WHERE 
o.order_status_id > '0' AND op.vendor_id = '37' AND 
DATE(o.date_added) = DATE('2012-10-11') AND o.order_status_id NOT IN (6,7) 
ORDER BY o.date_added DESC
```

Sorry it is too long query..the error I am getting is because the second sub-query which is this

```
(SELECT DISTINCT op.vendor_id FROM order_product op 
WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id) AS vendor_id
```

In above sub-query my target is to get vendor_id from order_product table and one order_id will have same vendor_id thats why I have added distinct but still mysql is giving error of multiple row.

How can I change this query..?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can your orders be served by different vendors? if yes, then you will need to rewrite your query from the scratch (join instead of subqueries is always a good idea). If you could live with "the first vendor found"... you could replace your distinct with an evil "LIMIT 1" at the end of the subquery for vendor-id...

Comment: distinct does not mean "one" row. It simply means all rows are different in at least one column. having to rely upon a DISTINCT usually points to a sloppy data model.

Comment: A number of subqueries there don't use 'DISTINCT'...

Comment: @Najzero No one order can not be served by different vendors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"distinct" does not cause the query to necessarily return only one row. "distinct" says to eliminate duplicate rows. So if, to make a simple example, you had a table with one column, and you had four records with values 1, 2, 2, and 3, then select without distinct would return four rows: 1, 2, 2, and 3. select distinct would return three rows: 1, 2, and 3.

Your query is fairly complex so I'm not sure just what you're trying to accomplish. You could force the subquery to return only one row by saying "select ... limit 1". Or you could replace all the fields in the select clause -- in this case just vendor_id I guess, with an aggregate, like select max(vendor_id). More likely, you need to add additional restrictions to the where clause so only one record will meet the conditions.

If you're expecting there to be only one qualifying record, but really there is more than one, then the problem is your data and not the query. If there can be more than one, than you need to figure out which one you want and modify the query to only get that one.

Comment: Thanks.. +1 for writing this _italic_ "the problem is your data" _italic_, I found data problem only.. Bdw thanks for this nice explanation..

Answer (score 0):

Distinct will always return multiple rows. you can either perform an inner join on some condition to restrict your rows or filter the rows on another specific condition.